# PHP - Search for specific file in FS and run shell command

Tags: php, python, search

I wrote a simple Python script that searches for a specific, unique file on a Unix-based filesystem and then runs a shell command based on the location of the file (in this example it calls cat).

```
from subprocess import call
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for file in files:
        if file == "sample.txt":
            result = (os.path.join(root, file))
            call (["cat", result])
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in PHP as well? I've looked into the glob() and exec() functions of PHP but I'm not sure how I can achieve the same thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{
    if (basename($file))== "sample.txt")
        shell_exec("cat " . $file);
}
?>
```

for additional info:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Cheers, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task using [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and the [exec function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) (as you already said) to execute commands.

Hope it helps,